# select data and exclude observations from a dataset via dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose to have:

```
x<-c(1,2,3,1)
y<-c(2,NA,1,1)
```

I want to create the following:

```
z<-c(2,2,3,1)
```

namely select the larger value, excluding NA a priori and keep the same value if x and y are equal.

Is there a way to do this in dplyr?

Comment: `pmax(x, y, na.rm=TRUE)`.

Comment: and with `dplyr`: data.frame(x=x, y=y) %>% mutate(z = pmax(x, y, na.rm=TRUE))

Answer (score 1):

We can use `pmax` in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
tibble(x, y) %>%
    transmute(xy = pmax(x, y, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
    pull(xy)
#[1] 2 2 3 1
```

---

Or another option is `reduce`

```
library(purrr)
list(x, y) %>%
     reduce(pmax, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 2 2 3 1
```